# Do I need a gravel pad beneath skids on my finished shed?

Tags: shed

I'm getting a 14x14 finished shed built in Austin, TX. The builders are using 30-year pressure treated 4x4 skids, which they raise off the ground on 4" blocks. The area drains well. They claim that this provides enough protection from rot.

Another guy I talked to said that I should either raise it 12" or put a gravel pad underneath (*which he'll do for a reasonable price*).

Which plan is correct?

Comment: This is firstly a matter of local conditions (humidity, rain, drainage) and secondly a matter of opinion (lifespan expectation). There's no right answer. FWIW, I'm in a very humid climate and I build my sheds on a rock base with no skids (treated floor framing on the rock). I expect them to last decades.

Comment: Note that the guy recommending the gravel pad is _happy_ (I'm sure) to do the work for a "reasonable" price. #NeverTrustaSalesman

Answer (score 3):

I would believe the builders over some guy any day.

Will a taller block and gravel make a difference? Sure it will but if you have good drainage it really won’t matter.

I have seen folks dig out earth and put rock down for the same reason “a guy said to” worst choice for them there soil was a high clay content so the rock pit filled and held water (yes it started to smell) a drainage system had to be added. If a simple plastic vapor barrier with the 4” blocks will do better than rock and taller blocking.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning if not with your opening statement. Shed builders are often hacks with no qualifications (no one inspects yard sheds). It's a logical fallacy (an appeal to authority) to believe them on title alone.

Comment: Good point: don't dig-out a rock pit. If anything, apply rocks on grade level.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless the wood rot question I would apply a layer of rocks with landscaping fabric underneath to make it unattractive for rodents and bugs.

To keep the moles & rats out I use a bed of large-potato sized rocks.

Keeping the weeds out with the fabric also helps with managing the moisture & bugs.